# php include several pages and loaded via one page

Tags: php

I need to create one page with including another at the bottom, which will be loaded everywhere. And it looks simple: `<?php include("page.php"); ?>` but than i'm coming to menu with idea of adding several included pages on one with advanced link like: `index.php?page=basic` so from `page=` id it would load included page.

[Here is small template example i have](http://jsfiddle.net/rksvxmdb/3/)

I've found this example:

```
<?php include("bottom.php"); ?>
```

As include function, but can include only *.php or also *.html file?

Comment: Yes. But trying it would probably have been faster that writing this question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are free to include a mixture of files with include() (be it html, text, PHP (which will be evaluated)

Comment: And the way of including is right or there is something else should be know... (<?php include("bottom.php"); ?>) like some security reasons or whetever?

Comment: Yes, that will include it properly (it will not require it though, so it will throw only a warning if it cannot access the file)

Comment: @AleksandrSubots If you're talking about user-uploaded files there are most definitely security issues.  See my answer for the reason why... basically PHP will execute whatever you include.  Really though there are then client-side attacks that can be done by including malicious JavaScript.  Be careful when dealing with user data.

Comment: html will be evaluated as well if there's a php opening tag in it.

Comment: no, no user files will be uploaded, just simple php page with included html/php pages inside.

but what's about making links like (?page=) so when you're loading page with option, it would load page with included page?

Answer (score 2):

`include()` and `require()` can load any file you want.  However, those files will always be executed as PHP.  If it's just plain HTML, then there is no PHP to execute.  But if your HTML file has `<?php` in it, then it will run as PHP.  This is an important distinction.

If you simply want to output a static HTML file, use `readfile()` instead.  This is faster as it doesn't have to execute anything, and reads the file directly to the output buffer.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Also, if you are accepting a file by parameter to load (`file=index.html` for example), then be sure that the file is in the path you expect it to be.  Use `dirname` to ensure it is within the document root so you don't have people doing something like `file=../../../../../../etc/passwd` or similar.

Comment: All included pages have only HTML content and there is NO php in included pages.

Comment: @AleksandrSubots Then I recommend using `readfile()` for efficiency.

Comment: this is the right answer. using include to load plain text, when you aren't certain of that .txt contents is a security risk